# How to set request header to access Hasura GraphQL Heroku server in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, http-headers, hasura

I am not able to send a POST request to my Hasura endpoint from my Flutter client and even from POSTMAN.

Here is my current error:

> {"errors":[{"extensions":{"path":"$","code":"invalid-json"},"message":"Error
> in $: not enough input"}]}

I added endpoint `my_endpoint/v1/graphql` and `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET` which I set in Heroku dashboard. ( This value now shows up on my deployed herokuapp console)

My client is using [ferry-graphql](https://github.com/gql-dart/ferry) like this

```
Client initClient(String url, String secret) {
  final link = HttpLink(
    url,
    defaultHeaders: {
      'x-hasura-admin-secret': secret,
    },
  );
  final cache = Cache();

  final client = Client(
    link: link,
    cache: cache,
  );
  return client;
}
```

I am not sure what else I should add for my client request header to access hasura.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you: https://github.com/gql-dart/ferry/issues/95#issuecomment-848735562